# Change color of part of the line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, color

Imagine a few km long pipeline. Pipeline consists of 4 types of pipe. Those types are alternating.

- 0 - 200m  A type of pipe go. (Green color)
- 200 - 230m B type of pipe etc..(RED color)
- 230 - 380m C type of pipe etc..(YELLOW color)
- .. 10 000m A type of pipe go. (Green color)

In QGIS I have whole line in one color, no point, just **line***. Line is not 
straight. Is it possible to change color, part by part?

***EDIT: its kml file so I have no data, just line**

Comment: This is a relatively straight forward task and easy. Given... how is your linestring categorized? Has it been actually split into segments and attributed with the "Types"? If not you should do that as a first step.

Comment: @SaultDon no it wasnt, its kml file so I have no data, just line.

Comment: You should give those kind of 'details' right from the start ... if you have no data the answers given so far won't fit your needs ...

Comment: I have updated question. 
but @MrXsquared mentioned B) Using Line length, I was thinking this may work.

Comment: Just updated my answer and added an expression in case your layer is not projected. However, option B should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Apply a categorized or rule-based style on it.

**A) Using a type field**

Go to layer properties and open symbology tab. Choose "Categorized" and for "Column" choose your `type` field:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**B) Using Line length**

If you do not have a `type` field you can also categorize it directly by its length. Note that your layer needs to be in a projected CRS.

Apply a rule based style and use the expression `$length`. It will return the length of line in meters (given you use a projected CRS!). So your rules will look like e.g. `$length > 0 AND $length <= 200`

[image]

You could also add length information to your attribute table if you want.

If your layer is not in a projected CRS and you do not want to reproject it, you could use an expression like this instead of `$length`:

```
length(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:3395'))
```

Instead of `EPSG:3395` use one that fits your region the best.

Comment: I have updated question.